# converting xhtml to xml in r

Tags: r, xml, xhtml

I want to parse a court document I downloaded in xml format. But the response type is application/xhtml+xml. And I'm getting an error in turning this xhtml document to xml in r so that I can extract information I need. See below. Can anyone help? Thank you.

```
resp_xml <- readRDS("had_NH_xml.rds")

# Load xml2
library(xml2)

# Check response is XML
http_type(resp_xml)
[1] "application/xhtml+xml"

# Examine returned text with content()
NH_text <- content(resp_xml, as = "text") 
NH_text
[1] "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\n        \t<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" /><link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/csologin/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-redmond\" /><link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/csologin/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3\" /><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/csologin/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/csologin/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/csologin/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/csologin/javax.faces.resource/primefaces-extensions.js.jsf?ln=primefaces-extensions&amp;v=4.0.0\"></script><link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/csologin/javax.faces.resou... <truncated>
> 
> # Check htmltidy package: https://cran.r-     project.org/web/packages/htmltidy/htmltidy.pdf
> 
# Turn NH_text into an XML document
NH_xml <- read_xml(NH_text)
```

> Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url,
>   as_html = as_html,  : 
>             Entity 'nbsp' not defined [26]

Comment: Having the actual document wld rly help folks help you. The `xml2` or even `XML`  pkg cld likely work but we haven't seen any idea of your issue beyond a random error w/no document context.

Comment: By default, XML only recognises the five entity names &lt;, &gt;, &amp;, &quot; and &apos; Other entities are only recognised if you explicitly define them, e.g. in a DTD, and XHTML5 does not have a DTD. So that explains the error. But what exactly are you trying to do? XHTML is already XML.

Comment: Thank you, all. Adding an additional argument like below solved the problem. I apologize for not being clear with my question. It was my first post ever on stackoverflow.com. I hope to learn fast.                                                                                                                                                                                                         NH_xml <- read_xml(NH_text, as_html = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

Named HTML entities are invalid in XML (regardless of what any potential troll comments might otherwise "suggest"). I do not know R programming though what I can tell you is that you need to do string replacement for the following array:

```
'&nbsp;','&gt;','&lt;'
```

...and replace them with the following strings:

```
'&#160;','&#60;','&#62;'
```

In PHP this would simply be:

```
$f = array('&nbsp;','&gt;','&lt;');
$r = array('&#160;','&#60;','&#62;');
$a = str_ireplace($f,$r,$a);
```

...and each relative key/value would be replaced, I'm not sure enough to try to post R code looking at basic tutorials though.

What I *can* tell you is that if you clean out those strings (and any doctype) then if the rest of the code is not malformed then it *should* render just fine as `application/xml`.